# Browsing with a Session per Tab

Tags: browser

I need to login to a site that I am developing with four different users at the same time.

Currently, I am using four different browsers, or two browsers (chrome and firefox) two times (incognito-private / normal)

But this arrangement is tedious. I do not want to have four windows. **I want only one window with four tabs.** Using tabs is easier and faster for me because I will be switching between tabs constantly.

Yoono plugin for firefox seems to do what I want but I prefer to stay away from a service that makes me register one social network.

I am not constraint to any of the major browsers. I could use Firefox, Chrome, or IE (for windows).

Is there a Windows browser that have session per tab? Or a plugin for one of them to accomplish the same task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now there is Brave Browser that allows create tabs with different sessions.

Comment: Brave browser no longer support new session for each tab

Answer (score 0):

A bit late I know, but I found this "Private Tab" plugin does the trick.  It opens up a new tab in Private Browsing Mode, they are private and separated from each other...

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/private-tab/

Comment: I just tried. It does open a private tab. But if you open two private tabs, they are not indpendent from each other. Try login to gmail in a private tab.. and then open another private tab. If you go to gmail in this second tab, you'll be already logged in.

Comment: Ah that's a shame, back to the drawing board then I guess.

Answer (score 0):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/ is what you are after.

> Under the hood, it separates website storage into tab-specific Containers. Cookies downloaded by one Container are not available to other Containers. With the Firefox Multi-Account Containers extension, you can...
>
> - Sign in to two different accounts on the same site (for example, you
>   could sign in to work email and home email in two different Container
>   tabs.
> - Keep different kinds of browsing far away from each other (for
>   example, you might use one Container tab for managing your Checking
>   Account and a different Container tab for searching for new songs by
>   your favorite band)
> - Avoid leaving social-network footprints all over
>   the web (for example, you could use a Container tab for signing in to
>   a social network, and use a different tab for visiting online news
>   sites, keeping your social identity separate from tracking scripts on
>   news sites)

Answer (score -1):

This is an old thread, but the topic is still relevant to a valuable workflow.

Session Box is exactly what you need, in chrome.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sessionbox-multi-login-to/megbklhjamjbcafknkgmokldgolkdfig

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)